# Bokeh - Update charts on database update

Tags: python, bokeh

**EDIT :** I fixed the `TypeError` by using ColumnDataSource.data in the update function, the question is now if this is the right approach to solve the problem.

I want to display a dashboard with info coming from a database, I'm new to Bokeh but I understood I need to run a Bokeh server application. My idea was to update the `ColumnDataSource` in a separate thread but I'm not sure it'll work.
Here's a test I've been trying to see if I can get the plot to update but I get `TypeError: 'ColumnDataSource' object is not iterable`

```
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
import time
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
from tornado import gen

from functools import partial

data = {'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [10, 20, 30, 40]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data)
p = figure(plot_width = 700, plot_height = 700, 
            title = 'Histogram of Arrival Delays by Carrier',
            x_axis_label = 'Delay (min)', y_axis_label = 'Proportion')

doc = curdoc()

@gen.coroutine
def update(x, y):
    source.data.update(ColumnDataSource({'x': x, 'y':y}).data)

def blocking_task():
    while True:
        # do some blocking computation
        time.sleep(5)
        x = [ randint(0,10) for _ in range(4)]
        y = [ randint(20, 80) for _ in range(4)]
        # but update the document from callback
        doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(update, x=x, y=y))

p.hbar(y='x', height=0.2, right='y', source=source)
doc.add_root(p)
thread = Thread(target=blocking_task)
thread.start()
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the right approach, provided that you **need** threading. One small correction: it is not necessary to create a new ColumnDataSource at each update. You can just assign the new data dictionary to the existing `source.data`. See slightly modified code below (works for Bokeh v1.0.4).

```
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
from tornado import gen
import time

data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
p = figure(plot_width = 700, plot_height = 700,
            title = 'Histogram of Arrival Delays by Carrier',
            x_axis_label = 'Delay (min)', y_axis_label = 'Proportion')

doc = curdoc()

@gen.coroutine
def update(x, y):
    source.data = {'x': x, 'y': y}

def blocking_task():
    while True:
        # do some blocking computation
        time.sleep(5)
        x = [ randint(0, 10) for _ in range(4)]
        y = [ randint(20, 80) for _ in range(4)]
        # but update the document from callback
        doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(update, x = x, y = y))

p.hbar(y = 'x', height = 0.2, right = 'y', source = source)
doc.add_root(p)
thread = Thread(target = blocking_task)
thread.start()
```

If you don't need threading then it is easier to use approach based on **periodic callback**:

```
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from random import randint
import time

data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)
p = figure(plot_width = 700, plot_height = 700,
            title = 'Histogram of Arrival Delays by Carrier',
            x_axis_label = 'Delay (min)', y_axis_label = 'Proportion')
p.hbar(y = 'x', height = 0.2, right = 'y', source = source)

def update():
    x = [ randint(0, 10) for _ in range(4)]
    y = [ randint(20, 80) for _ in range(4)]
    source.data = {'x': x, 'y': y}

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 5000)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

You run the code using:

```
bokeh serve --show app.py
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, do you if there's a way to make this work in a jupyter notebook? `output_notebook()` doesn't show me the updates

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Jupyter Notebook

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html), you need to add `output_notebook()` after your imports, `push_notebook()` at the end of your `update` function, and a `show(p, notebook_handle=True)` when you display the layout.